# The close button does not close the modal

Tags: javascript

I have a modal that opens when a user clicks the 'start here' button, after clicking next on the first modal it goes to the next three modals automatically, then it goes to the last modal with a form. I have two "close" onclicks, one on the first modal and the other on the last modal. The problem is that the modal closes on the first one but not on the last one. I need it to close on the last one too.

My code is here:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var modal2 = document.getElementById("myModal2");
var modal3 = document.getElementById("myModal3");
var modal4 = document.getElementById("myModal4");
var modal5 = document.getElementById("myModal5");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("myBtn3");
var btn4 = document.getElementById("myBtn4");
var btn5 = document.getElementById("myBtn5");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

btn2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(() => {
    modal3.style.display = "block";
  }, 4500);
  setTimeout(() => {
    modal4.style.display = "block";
  }, 8500);
  setTimeout(() => {
    modal5.style.display = "block";
  }, 12900);
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  modal2.style.display = "none";
  modal3.style.display = "none";
  modal4.style.display = "none";
  modal5.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal5) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal2.style.display = "none";
    modal3.style.display = "none";
    modal4.style.display = "none";
    modal5.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.showthis {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10000 !important;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  overflow-y: hidden;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #ededed;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 6px solid #d1222b;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #d1222b;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mgl-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.slide-1-img {
  height: 98.75vh;
}

.mgl-col-2 {
  align-self: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.mgl-col-2 .content {
  margin: auto;
  align-self: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.mgl-col-2 .content h2 {
  color: #d1222b;
  font-size: 54px;
  line-height: 64px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.mgl-col-2 input {
  width: 100%;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mgl-col-3 {
  margin: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.mgl-col-3 .content {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.mgl-col-3 .content h3 {
  color: #d1222b;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.mgl-col-3 .content h2 {
  color: #0a314b;
  font-size: 54px;
}

.mt-50 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.progress-line {
  width: 100px;
  height: 5px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}

.progress-line.red-bg {
  background: #d1222b;
}

.sm-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  opacity: .75;
}

.j-center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal-btn {
  padding: 20px 25px;
  background: #d1222b;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

.modal-btn:hover {
  background: #3c3c3c;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-box {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#myModal5 input {
  width: 35%;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#myModal5 .modal-content {
  background-image: url('https://www.rsisecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/image-2.jpg');
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#myModal5 h2 {
  color: white;
}

#myModal5 h2 span {
  color: #d1222b;
}

#myModal5 p {
  color: #fff;
}

#myModal5 .btn-box {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#myModal5 .rsi-logo {
  width: 100px;
}

#myBtn {
  color: black;
}

.text-left {
  text-align: left !important;
}


/* iPad Pro */

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .slide-1-img {
    height: 98.75vh;
    width: 400px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}


/* iPad */

@media (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .slide-1-img {
    height: 98.75vh;
    width: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  #myModal .mgl-col-2 .content {
    margin: auto;
    align-self: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 25px;
  }
  #myModal .mgl-col-2 .content h2 {
    font-size: 42px;
    line-height: 52px;
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
  .mgl-col-3 .content h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  #myModal5 h2 {
    font-size: 34px;
  }
}


/* Mobile Landscape */

@media (min-width: 560px) and (max-width: 759px) {}

@media screen and (min-width:992px) {}


/* Mobile */

@media only screen and (max-width: 559px) {
  .mgl-col-1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #myModal .mgl-col-2 .content h2 {
    color: #d1222b;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 46px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  #myModal .modal-content {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
  .btn-box {
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
  }
  .mgl-col-3 .content {
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .mgl-col-3 .content h2 {
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .mgl-col-3 .content h3 {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .mt-50 {
    margin-top: 35px;
  }
  .progress-line {
    width: 50px;
    height: 3px;
  }
  .mgl-col-3 .content {
    width: 90%;
  }
  #myModal5 input {
    width: 45%;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  .sm-text {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    opacity: .75;
  }
  #myModal5 h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
  #myModal5 .rsi-logo {
    width: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
}


/* iPhone */

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {}


/* Galaxy S5 */

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {}


/* iPhone 5 */

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {}


/* Galaxy Fold */

@media only screen and (max-width: 280px) {}
```

```html
<div class="white-outlined-btn width-50 m-auto " id="myBtn">Start Here</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<form>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal" style="display:none;">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <div class="mgl-row">
        <div class="mgl-col-1">
          <img src="https://www.rsisecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/image.jpg" alt="free assessment" class="slide-1-img">
        </div>
        <div class="mgl-col-2">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="https://www.rsisecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/rsi-logo.svg" alt="rsi logo" class="rsi-logo">
            <h2 class="text-left">
              Get your FREE <br> Cyber Risk Score <br> Assessment
            </h2>
            <p class="text-left">
              Enter URL Below:
            </p>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Website" id="Website" placeholder="Enter URL" required="required">

            <div class="btn-box">
              <a class="modal-btn" id="myBtn2">Start Here</a>
            </div>

            <!--p class="sm-text">
                    By clicking "START HERE" you are accepting <br>
                    lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                </p-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- The Modal 2 -->
  <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="mgl-row">
        <div class="mgl-col-3">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="https://www.rsisecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/rsi-logo.svg" alt="rsi logo" class="rsi-logo">

            <h3>
              01 of 03
            </h3>
            <h2>
              Checking Network Vulnerability
            </h2>
            <!--p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                </p-->
            <div class="mgl-row j-center mt-50">
              <div class="progress-line red-bg"></div>
              <div class="progress-line"></div>
              <div class="progress-line"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>


  <!-- The Modal 3 -->
  <div id="myModal3" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="mgl-row">
        <div class="mgl-col-3">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="https://www.rsisecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/rsi-logo.svg" alt="rsi logo" class="rsi-logo pb-0">

            <h3 class="mtop-002">
              02 of 03
            </h3>
            <h2 class="mobile-custom-9372">
              Scanning Dark Web Discovery
            </h2>
            <!--p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                </p-->
            <div class="mgl-row j-center mt-50">
              <div class="progress-line red-bg"></div>
              <div class="progress-line red-bg"></div>
              <div class="progress-line"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>

  </div>


  <!-- The Modal 4 -->
  <div id="myModal4" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="mgl-row">
        <div class="mgl-col-3">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="https://www.rsisecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/rsi-logo.svg" alt="rsi logo" class="rsi-logo">

            <h3>
              03 of 03
            </h3>
            <h2>
              Web Vulnerability & Generating IP Threat Analysis
            </h2>
            <!--p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                </p-->
            <div class="mgl-row j-center mt-50">
              <div class="progress-line red-bg"></div>
              <div class="progress-line red-bg"></div>
              <div class="progress-line red-bg"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- The Modal 5 -->
  <div id="myModal5" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>

      <div class="mgl-row">
        <div class="mgl-col-3" style="margin-top:0px;">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="https://www.rsisecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/logo-white.svg" alt="rsi logo" class="rsi-logo pb-4">

            <h2>
              Generate your FREE <span>Cyber Risk Assessment</span>
            </h2>
            <p>
              Where should we send it to?
            </p>
            <input name="First Name" id="First Name" placeholder="First Name" required="required">
            <input name="Last Name" id="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name" required="required">
            <br>
            <input name="Company" id="Company" placeholder="Company" required="required">
            <input name="Title" id="Title" placeholder="Job Title" required="required">
            <br>
            <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
            <input name="Phone" id="Phone" placeholder="Phone" required="required">
            <div class="btn-box">
              <button type="submit" class="modal-btn">Send Report</button>

            </div>
            <p class="sm-text">
              After submiting this form, please allow up to 48 hours to receive your comprehensive report via email. <br> All information obtained through our website will be utilized internally and will not be sold to any 3rd party entity.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide a [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is way too much code to sift through for such a simple problem. https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/

Comment: `var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];` only gets the first close button. You never add a click handler to the second close button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below clode by applying it inside the script tag and remove the line `var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];`,because it only gets the first element tag with the className as "close". So the second element tag with the className "close" isn't working.
you can declare another variable by getting the second tag with the className "close" like `var span1=document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1]` and use the eventHandling code too.

Or else you can directly apply the below code inside the script tag.

```
var span = document.querySelectorAll(".close");
for(var i=0;i<span.length;i++){
    span[i].addEventListener("click",hideSections)
}
function hideSections() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  modal2.style.display = "none";
  modal3.style.display = "none";
  modal4.style.display = "none";
  modal5.style.display = "none";
}
```